# Rounding to n decimal issues

Tags: python

I need to convert `5/7` to `20` decimal places
The following doesn't work (seems like max precision is 15):

`format(float(5)/float(7), '.%20f')` output is `0.714285714285714301575`

`round(float(n)/float(d) * 10**20)/10**20` output is `0.714285714286`

What am I doing wrong? What is the maximum precision for float?

Comment: Have you tried using the decimal type ... 
`from decimal import *

Decimal(5) / Decimal(7)` 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: See hint here:https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

Comment: How should I round Decimal(5) / Decimal(7)?

Comment: The first line of code in your question results in a `ValueError: Format specifier missing precision` in both Python 2 and 3. When using the `format()` function, you don't need to put `%` in the format string. Try using `format(float(5)/float(7), '.20f')` instead which will give `'0.71428571428571430157'`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me like this

**For Python 3.X**

```
>>> '{:.9f}'.format(8/3)
 '2.666666667'

>>> '{:.15f}'.format(8/3)
 '2.666666666666667'

>>> '{:.20f}'.format(8/3)
 '2.66666666666666651864'
```

**For Python 2.X**

```
>>> '{:.20f}'.format(8.0/3)
 '2.66666666666666651864'

>>> '{:.20f}'.format(8/3.0)
 '2.66666666666666651864'

>>> '{:.20f}'.format(float(8)/3)
 '2.66666666666666651864'

>>> '{:.20f}'.format(8/float(3))
 '2.66666666666666651864'
```

Comment: The OP wants to convert `5/7`, why didn't you use those values?

Comment: No reason, i just randomly picked. You can use 5/7 also, it will work

Comment: '{:.20f}'.format(5/7.0) gives '0.71428571428571430157' gives correct string, but I need float and float('{:.20f}'.format(5/7.0)) gives incorrect result.

Comment: float conversion will be shortened. You can use round((8/3), 20) for float, but float has a limitation of 16 decimal points.

Comment: What type doesn't have such limitations?

Comment: You can use decimal, just use from decimal import Decimal and then Decimal(8/3)

Comment: How do I add precision to Decimal(8/3)?

Comment: Decimal(5/7.0)
Decimal('0.7142857142857143015746146375022362917')
This is incorrect.